# Apk is not installing it is build from android 3.0

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have just installed android studio 3.0 ,have built hello world project and then copy my apk file into my android phone. I have started installing but it always showing "App not installed". I have used android studio previous versions also. I have never faced this type of problem. What is the solution for this? Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: just test case **Disable Instant run than Build apk**

Comment: If by "built" you mean "clicked the Run button", [that APK is no longer easily usable for anything else](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html).

Comment: where I have to disable

Comment: `and then copy my apk file into my android phone.`. Unclear what you are doing. Why would you copy an apk -tou are not telling what you do exactly- if you can let Android Studio install and run it.

Comment: I did the same but its again not installed.

Comment: I just copied built apk file from the project and then pasted into my phone and then started installing apk.

Answer (score 0):

Before making the build, check if you have instant run enabled or not. It is enabled by default and can be found under `File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run`

Disable it and then try rebuilding the apk.

Now, if you are building a release apk and you have selected Signature Version V2(Full APK Signature), in the generate signed apk dialog, app might not install after the build is made.

You need to re-generate a signed apk with both the signature versions enabled i.e V1 & V2. You will get this option under Build -> Generate Signed APK.

Combining this with the disable instant run thing, your apk should install smoothly.

Comment: I want to install unsigned apk

Comment: signed apk is installing but unsigned apk is not installing why?